# Cypress Find specific ID within list of elements

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress, assertion

I want to assert that a specific ID exists in a list of elements,

**This is what I tried:**

```
assertSelectedIdMovedToAnotherList() {
  // selectedId yeilded from another function
  cy.get(@selectedId).then(($selectedId) => {
    cy.get(app .idListA).should('have.id', $selectedId)
  });
}
```

When I run this code in the test, I find the list but it compares only the first Id of the list to the selected ID,
and it always fails because it doesn't scan all the list's IDs..*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I have all the facts, but if for example this DOM

```
<ul>
  <li id="1"></li>
  <li id="2"></li>
  <li id="3"></li>
</ul>
```

you could test with

```
const targetId = '2';

cy.get('ul li')
  .should($els => expect([...$els].some(el => el.id === targetId)).to.eq(true))
```

to explain,

- `.should()` with and expect in the callback will retry until true (or timeout)
- `[...$els].some(...)` applies the test inside to every item, returns true if any succeed

A shorter way would be

```
cy.get('ul li#' + targetId);
```

In this selector, only the one with the targetId matches.
If targetId is not there, test fails.